# R: Error: invalid 'y' type in 'x || y'

Tags: r, date

I try to create a vector that contains the seasons, the dates of a different vector are in, i.e. if in the vector 'dates' there is "2012-06-06", I want in the vector 'jahreszeiten' to be "Summer". When I try it like this (somehow my Rstudio gives me german month names, allthough its user interface is english):

```
jahreszeit <- rep(NA, length(dates))
if(months(dates[i]) == "September" || "Oktober" || "November"){
  jahreszeit[i] <- "Herbst"
}
```

I get the error

```
Error in months(dates[i]) == "September" || "Oktober" : 
  invalid 'y' type in 'x || y'
```

(what does R want to tell me with this message?)

while

```
if (months(dates[i]) == "Juni" || "Juli" || "August"){
  jahreszeit[i] <- "Sommer"
}
```

gives me no error and works fine. I tried to solve the problem like this:

```
monate <- levels(as.factor(months(dates)))
if (as.factor(months(dates[i])) == monate[9] || monate[1] || monate[8]){
  jahreszeit[i] <- "Frühling"
}
```

but it doesn't help still

```
Error in as.factor(months(dates[i])) == monate[9] || monate[1] : 
      invalid 'y' type in 'x || y').
```

Thanks for your efforts,

Matthias

> In order to execute the example use:

```
dates <- c("2012-06-05", "2012-06-05", "2012-06-05", "2012-06-05", "2012-06-05", 
"2012-06-05", "2012-06-05", "2012-06-06", "2012-06-06", "2012-06-06", 
"2012-06-06", "2012-06-06", "2012-06-06", "2012-06-06", "2012-06-06", 
"2012-06-05", "2012-06-05", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", 
"2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", 
"2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", 
"2013-04-18", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", 
"2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", 
"2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-25", 
"2013-04-25", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-26", 
"2013-04-26", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-26", 
"2013-04-26", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", 
"2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", 
"2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", 
"2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-07", 
"2013-06-19", "2013-06-19", "2013-06-26", "2013-06-26", "2013-06-26", 
"2013-06-26", "2013-06-26", "2013-06-27", "2013-06-27", "2013-06-27", 
"2013-06-27", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", 
"2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", 
"2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", 
"2013-07-04", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", 
"2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", 
"2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-11", 
"2013-07-11", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", 
"2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", 
"2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", 
"2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", 
"2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", 
"2013-07-16", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-10", "2013-07-10", "2013-07-10", 
"2013-07-25", "2013-07-25", "2013-07-25", "2013-07-25", "2013-07-25", 
"2013-07-31", "2013-07-31", "2013-07-31", "2013-07-31", "2013-07-31", 
"2013-07-31", "2013-07-31", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-01", "2013-08-01", 
"2013-08-01", "2013-08-01", "2013-08-01", "2013-08-01", "2013-08-14", 
"2013-08-14", "2013-08-14", "2013-08-14", "2013-08-14", "2013-08-14", 
"2013-08-14", "2013-08-14", "2013-08-28", "2013-08-28", "2013-08-28", 
"2013-08-28", "2013-08-28", "2013-08-28", "2013-08-28", "2013-08-28", 
"2013-09-11", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-11", 
"2013-09-11", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-26", "2013-09-26", 
"2013-09-26", "2013-09-26", "2013-09-26", "2013-09-26", "2013-09-26", 
"2013-09-26", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-09", 
"2013-10-09", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-23", 
"2013-10-23", "2013-10-23", "2013-10-23", "2013-10-23", "2013-10-23", 
"2013-10-23", "2013-10-23", "2013-10-01", "2013-10-01", "2013-10-01", 
"2013-10-01", "2013-10-01", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-09", 
"2013-11-06", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-06", 
"2013-11-06", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", 
"2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", 
"2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", 
"2013-11-05", "2013-11-05", "2013-11-05", "2013-11-05", "2013-11-05", 
"2013-11-05", "2013-11-05", "2013-11-05", "2013-11-26", "2013-11-26", 
"2013-11-26", "2013-11-26", "2013-11-26", "2013-12-03", "2013-12-03", 
"2013-12-04", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-04", 
"2013-12-04", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-18", "2013-12-18", 
"2014-02-12", "2014-02-12", "2014-03-10", "2014-03-10", "2014-04-07", 
"2014-04-07", "2014-04-07", "2014-04-07", "2014-04-07", "2014-04-07", 
"2014-04-07", "2014-04-08", "2014-04-08", "2014-04-08", "2014-04-08", 
"2014-04-08", "2014-04-10", "2014-04-10", "2014-04-10", "2014-04-14", 
"2014-04-14", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-14", 
"2014-04-14", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-14", 
"2014-04-15", "2014-04-15", "2014-04-15", "2014-04-15", "2014-04-15", 
"2014-04-24", "2014-04-24", "2014-05-14", "2014-05-14", "2014-05-26", 
"2014-05-26", "2014-06-11", "2014-06-11", "2014-06-11", "2014-06-11", 
"2014-06-11", "2014-06-11", "2014-06-11", "2014-06-11", "2014-06-26", 
"2014-06-26", "2014-06-26", "2014-06-26", "2014-06-26", "2014-06-26", 
"2014-07-09", "2014-07-09", "2014-07-09", "2014-07-15", "2014-07-15", 
"2014-07-15", "2014-07-15", "2014-07-15", "2014-07-15", "2014-07-21", 
"2014-07-21", "2014-07-21", "2014-07-22", "2014-07-22", "2014-07-22", 
"2014-07-22", "2014-07-22", "2014-07-22", "2014-08-05", "2014-12-16", 
"2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", 
"2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", 
"2014-12-16", "2014-12-16", "2015-05-05", "2015-05-05", "2015-05-07", 
"2015-05-07", "2015-05-07", "2015-05-07", "2015-05-07", "2015-05-07", 
"2015-05-07", "2015-05-07", "2015-05-07", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", 
"2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", 
"2015-05-11", "2015-05-12", "2015-05-12", "2015-05-12", "2015-05-12", 
"2015-05-12", "2015-05-12", "2015-05-12", "2015-05-12", "2015-05-18", 
"2015-05-18", "2015-05-18", "2015-05-18", "2015-05-18", "2015-05-18", 
"2015-05-19", "2015-05-19", "2015-05-19", "2015-05-19", "2015-05-19", 
"2015-05-19", "2015-05-21", "2015-05-21", "2015-05-21", "2015-05-21", 
"2015-05-21", "2015-05-21", "2015-07-15", "2015-07-15", "2015-07-20", 
"2015-07-20", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-21", 
"2015-07-21", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", 
"2015-07-23", "2015-08-04", "2015-08-04", "2015-08-04", "2015-08-06", 
"2015-08-06", "2015-08-06", "2015-08-06", "2015-08-06", "2015-08-06", 
"2015-08-06", "2015-08-06", "2015-08-06", "2015-08-11", "2015-08-11", 
"2015-08-11", "2015-08-11", "2015-08-11", "2015-08-12", "2015-09-29", 
"2015-09-29", "2015-09-29", "2015-09-29", "2015-09-29", "2015-09-29", 
"2015-09-29", "2015-09-29", "2015-09-29", "2015-09-29", "2015-10-12", 
"2015-10-12", "2015-10-12", "2015-10-12", "2015-11-16", "2015-11-16", 
"2015-11-16", "2015-11-16", "2015-11-16", "2015-11-16", "2015-12-15", 
"2015-12-15", "2015-12-15", "2016-01-28", "2016-01-28", "2016-01-28", 
"2016-01-28", "2016-01-28", "2016-02-03", "2016-02-03", "2016-02-03", 
"2016-02-03", "2016-02-03", "2016-02-03", "2016-02-03", "2016-02-03", 
"2016-02-03")
```

Comment: In R, logical comparisons are done as, e.g. `if (x == 1 || x == 2)` rather than `if (x == 1 || 2)`. This is not valid syntax: `months(dates[i]) == "September" || "Oktober" || "November"`

Comment: You are looking for `help("%in%")`. (And of course, @nrussel is correct, but forgot to mention that you should use `|` instead of `||` to compare vectors.)

Comment: @ nrussell: Well, this does prevent the error message from appearing, but my vector 'jahreszeit' doesn't change.

Comment: @mattu that depends on what `i` is. In your code there is no `i` defined, so I get the whole time "cannot find object i".

Comment: Please provide code for creating a `dates` vector that is valid syntax. The easiest solution for this task is using a look-up table and `merge` or `match` or a factor.

Comment: @ Joris Meys: you're right! I still had some "i" from a previous calculation. That explains why only one of those exactly analougue syntax phrases worked!

Comment: @Roland I'm sorry. I finally managed copy pasting via the function `dput`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're trying to do, is the following:

```
# create a character vector
jahreszeit <- character(length(dates))

id.fruhling <- months(dates) %in% c("mar", "apr", "may")
jahreszeit[id.fruhling] <- "fruhling"
```

etc...

Please take a look again at a good tutorial on R. From your code it's clear you don't realize how to write your code so it works on complete vectors.

PS: note that I use some random abbreviation of the months. Depending on the machine you run that code (and its language settings), those months will be different. A better way to do this, is to use `as.POSIXlt` so you have the number of the month instead of the language-dependent name.

So something like this is how I would tackle it:

```
dates <- c("2012-06-05",
           "2013-09-12",
           "2014-01-05",
           "2009-04-12")
# find number of the month
month.nr <- as.POSIXlt(dates)$mon + 1
# create a lookup table
jzeiten <- c(rep('winter',2),
             rep(c('fruhling','summer','herbst'), each = 3),
             'winter')
# use vectorization and indices
jahreszeiten <- jzeiten[month.nr]

# profit
jahreszeiten
```